# GNOME Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS and Enablement Stack?

Tags: gnome, lts

I am confused with some points with 
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuGNOME

If I install this version whith Enablement Stack I will have security updates for 3 years? or by August 2016?

I will receive the next 14.04.4 through system update tool or have to reinstall?

and when 14.04.5 have to reinstall the system?